# Difference between two dates yields different results

Tags: pandas, date, date-formatting

Below is the example of a sample pandas dataframe and I am trying to find the difference between the dates in the two rows (with least dated row as the base - in this case second row).
The difference between 2 dates is > than 90 days, hence I am expecting "false" for 2 rows. But for some reason, the result looks different.

```
PH_number   date        Type
H09879721   2018-10-29  AccountHolder
H09879731   2018-07-24  AccountHolder

Code:
print(df.date.diff()<=pd.Timedelta(90,'d'))

Current Result:
False
True

Expected Result:
False
False
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa: The dates should be within 90 days - hence I believe <= would work best

Comment: Please [`accept and upvote`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it provided your required result.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`abs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html) this takes care when difference is negative:

```
df.date.diff().abs().dt.days<=90
```

Or:

```
df.date.diff().abs().dt.days.le(90)
```

Or:

```
df.date.diff().abs()<=pd.Timedelta(90,'d')
```

Or:

```
df.date.diff().abs().le(pd.Timedelta(90,'d'))
```

---

```
0    False
1    False
Name: date, dtype: bool
```